# Why is my For Each loop so slow? Is there a more efficent way?

Tags: excel, vba

I try to search text contents (~30 criterials) in a big data sheet (nearly 300k cells in 20 Columns). The cells in this sheet are strings with a lenght between 6 and 139 letters and the cells I'm looking for have a lenght of 6. I've tried it with this code but this takes a extremely long time (I've never waited to end):

```
Sub DeleteAllCellsWithSpecificContent()


Dim c As Object
Dim rng1 As Range

Dim z As Object
Dim rng2 As Range

Set c = Sheets("Liste").Range("A2")
Set rng1 = Sheets("Liste").Range("A2:S40000")

Set z = Sheets("Auswertung").Range("B2")
Set rng2 = Sheets("Auswertung").Range("B2:B31")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each z In rng2
    For Each c In rng1

        If InStr(1, c, z) Then
            c.Clear 'Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It is slow because you have a nested loop (loop inside a loop). Research for `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` it returns the row number if a full value was found in a range. Or use `Range.Find` to look for parts of a string too. So you only need one loop which should make it a lot faster.

Comment: Looping over `Range` objects is slow. Looping over arrays in memory would speed things up.

Comment: Your `InStr()` is executed nearly 2.3 million times and you're looping over `Range` objects, what do you expect?

Comment: @JvdV Could you give a more specific approach?

Comment: @Nacorid Then what do you think how I could do it better? If there is a other way let me know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving the data to a Variant Array and looping that will speed things up a lot.

You can do the replacements within the array, then place the whole thing back on the sheet at the end.  This will work if there are *no* formula in rng1 (if there are they will get replaced with their current values)

```
Sub DeleteAllCellsWithSpecificContent()
    Dim c As Variant
    Dim rng1 As Range

    Dim z As Variant
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Set rng1 = Sheets("Liste").Range("A2:S40000")
    Set rng2 = Sheets("Auswertung").Range("B2:B31")

    Dim v1, v2

    v1 = rng1.Value2
    v2 = rng2.Value2

    Dim r1 As Long, c1 As Long, r2 As Long, c2 As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For r2 = 1 To UBound(v2, 1)
        z = v2(r2, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(z) Then
            For c1 = 1 To UBound(v1, 2)
                For r1 = 1 To UBound(v1, 1)
                    c = v1(r1, c1)
                    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
                        If InStr(1, c, z) Then
                            v1(r1, c1) = Empty
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next

    rng1 = v1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, that's instant. Thanks for your advice and efforts.

Comment: Learning to use Arrays in Excel is one of the best things you'll ever do. +1